# How to ask my manager for a list of key result areas professionally?

Tags: professionalism, manager

I'm starting a new job soon and I'm unsure what my key result areas are. I want to be able to manage my time effectively and thus only want to be working on tasks that are relevant to my job.

To provide me with a "track to run on". I want to acquire a list from my manager detailing what my key result areas are.

What is a professional way of asking for this information?

Comment: You go to your boss and ask "Can you help me define my key goals and metrics for them ? "

Comment: Since you didn't start yet, the first day is the perfect opportunity to do it.

Comment: can't fail a task if you haven't been assigned it yet

Comment: @Hilmar You missed an answer opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your manager will manage you, and will thus give you tasks to complete after your induction completes (if applicable).

You won't be given a desk and not told what you should be doing.  At least you shouldn't be, and if that happens, you should ask.

But assume that things will happen when you start and work from there.

Comment: _You won't be given a desk and not told what you should be doing_ You just made my day. You should probably qualify that a bit. I've seen that as the norm in three major Silicon Valley companies.

Comment: To be fair a major silicon valley company would probably use that tactic as a test for initiative.  For more normal jobs, you'll generally be told who you're working with and what to do and there'll usally be some mentorship going on.